# Windows cmd.exe command passed Perl system function needs double quotes in some cases?

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

The Windows cmd.exe command 'type \Test\hello.txt' must be surrounded with double quotes in order for the Perl system() function to execute it properly.  I don't find this documented at https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system or at https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport#system  - **is the requirement for double quotes on Windows documented anywhere?**

The following sample code demonstrates the issue when run with command `perl \my\perl\perlsystest` in a Windows Command Prompt window on a Windows 10 Pro server at version 2004 (OS Build 19041.867) with Perl at level v5.26.3

```
$cmd='type \Test\hello.txt' ;   # Set Windows DOS command to be executed
system('ECHO '.$cmd) ;          # Display command to be executed
system($cmd) == 0               # Execute command - note "\Test\hello.txt not found" error but with $? == 0
  or die "system(\"$cmd\") failed: $?!" ;
if ($? == -1) {print "system(\"$cmd\") failed to execute: $!!\n"}
elsif ($? & 127) {printf "system(\"$cmd\") child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
  ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without' ; exit}
elsif ($? != 0) {printf "system(\"$cmd\") child exited with value %d\n", $? ; exit}

$cmd='"'.$cmd.'"' ;             # Surround command string in double quotes
system('ECHO '.$cmd) ;          # Display command to be executed
system($cmd) == 0               # Execute command - note that command succeeds
  or die "system(\"$cmd\") failed: $?!" ;
if ($? == -1) {print "system(\"$cmd\") failed to execute: $!!\n"}
elsif ($? & 127) {printf "system(\"$cmd\") child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
  ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without' ; exit}
elsif ($? != 0) {printf "system(\"$cmd\") child exited with value %d\n", $? ; exit}

$cmd='type \Test\10hello.txt' ; # Set Windows DOS command to be executed
system('ECHO '.$cmd) ;          # Display command to be executed -  note that "type \Teshello.txt" is echoed
system($cmd) == 0               # Execute command - note "\Test\hello.txt not found" error but with $? == 0
  or die "system(\"$cmd\") failed: $?!" ;
if ($? == -1) {print "system(\"$cmd\") failed to execute: $!!\n"}
elsif ($? & 127) {printf "system(\"$cmd\") child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
  ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without' ; exit}
elsif ($? != 0) {printf "system(\"$cmd\") child exited with value %d\n", $? ; exit}

system('"ECHO '.$cmd).'"' ;     # Display command to be executed (with ECHO command in double quotes)
$cmd='"'.$cmd.'"' ;             # Surround command string in double quotes
system($cmd) == 0               # Execute command
  or die "system(\"$cmd\") failed: $?!" ;
if ($? == -1) {print "system(\"$cmd\") failed to execute: $!!\n"}
elsif ($? & 127) {printf "system(\"$cmd\") child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
  ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without' ; exit}
elsif ($? != 0) {printf "system(\"$cmd\") child exited with value %d\n", $? ; exit}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce with my Perl 5.30 on Windows 10 Pro (the script executes normally without any error).

Comment: [Win32::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ShellQuote) is useful.

Comment: @Mofi & @ikegami, thanks for your comments. Synthesizing those comments: When handling a `system()` call, Perl sends to Windows a command built by appending the argument(s) passed to the system() call to the value in the `sh` variable (from Perl Config.pm).

On my Windows 10, `perl -V:sh` displays `sh='cmd /x /c'`, so when `system($cmd)` is called with `$cmd='type \Test\hello.txt'`, the claim is that Perl will cause Windows to run the command `cmd /x /c type \Test\hello.txt`.

Comment: But that cannot be entirely correct, since `cmd /x /c type \Test\hello.txt` on my Windows 10 correctly types the `\Test\hello.txt` file but when `system($cmd)` is called with `$cmd='type \Test\hello.txt'`, the `system($cmd)` call throws error message `\Test\hello.txt not found` but returns `$?=0`.

Comment: My thanks to @Dada, who promptly commented, "I can't reproduce with my Perl 5.30 on Windows 10 Pro (the script executes normally without any error)".

Comment: @Dada, I currently have ActiveState Perl v5.26.3 installed.  Gabor Szabo (at https://perlmaven.com/download-and-install-perl) recommends Strawberry Perl (https://strawberryperl.com/), so I downloaded and installed Strawberry Perl v5.30.3.

I see the same output from `perlsystest` with either version of Perl.  Please note that `perlsystest` does not fail with an error.  Instead, the first `system($cmd)` call in `perlsystest` fails to properly execute `$cmd='type \Test\hello.txt'` and throws error message `\Test\hello.txt not found` but returns `$?=0`!?!!

Comment: @ikegami You recommended https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ShellQuote.  It isn't clear which subroutine you are recommending.  Do you recommend using one of them in particular?

On the Win32::ShellQuote web page, I see, "Windows passes its arguments as a single string instead of an array as other platforms do. In almost all cases, the standard Win32 CommandLineToArgvW function is used to parse this string. cmd.exe has different rules for handling quoting, so extra work has to be done if it is involved."

Comment: @ikegami If I had a C compiler on my Windows 10 workstation, I would try running ArgArrayPtr=CommandLineToArgvW("cmd /x /c type \Test\hello.txt\0",*pNumArgs) and ArgArrayPtr=CommandLineToArgvW("cmd /x /c type \"\Test\hello.txt\"\0",*pNumArgs) and have a look at the returned argument arrays.  If I did this, do you think I would learn anything useful?

Comment: Re "*Do you recommend using one of them in particular?*", For `system`? `quote_system_string`. "returns a single string" "to be passed to system or exec"

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you give to [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) has to be appropriate for the thing that will handle the command. The comments to the original question should be turned into an answer.

The `system` docs point to [exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec), which also says:

> When the arguments get executed via the system shell, results are subject to its quirks and capabilities. See "`STRING`" in perlop for details.

This also points to the entry in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop) for backticks:

> How that string gets evaluated is entirely subject to the command interpreter on your system. On most platforms, you will have to protect shell metacharacters if you want them treated literally. This is in practice difficult to do, as it's unclear how to escape which characters.

Perl doesn't address individual systems here because it supports so many of them (even when everyone who used those have disappeared).

---

You posted a wall of text there, and I had to rewrite it to see what you were doing. Instead of repeating the same code, a subroutine (with some reasonable formatting) is polite to the reader :)

```
my @commands = (
    'type \Test\hello.txt',
    q("type \Test\hello.txt")
    'type \Test\10hello.txt',
    );

foreach my $command ( @commands ) {
    try_it( $command );
    }

sub try_it  {
    my( $cmd ) = @_;
    system('ECHO '.$cmd); 
    system($cmd) == 0               # Execute command
      or die qq(system("$cmd") failed: $?!) ;
    if ($? == -1) {
        print qq(system("$cmd") failed to execute: $!!\n);
        }
    elsif ($? & 127) {
        printf qq(system("$cmd") child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n),
            ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without' ; 
        }
    elsif ($? != 0) {
        printf qq(system("$cmd") child exited with value %d\n), $? ; 
        }
    }
```